ERROR: Required operator not found in expression:
I'm developing a process that will cycle through a file of about 1+ million rows to find the earliest record for my key value.  My Plan is to use global macro variables to share across 4 macros.  One macro will be the master that calls the other 3.  So depending on which macro was called, the global macro variables will be updated.
I'm in the process of testing a macro variable to do an update.
Here is the logic.
    %IF %EVAL(&ACCT_CT. = 1) 
    %THEN %DO;

        DATA _NULL_;

            SET BURNED_HLD;

            CALL SYMPUTX('G_EARN_PRD', 201708);
            CALL SYMPUTX('G_ACCT_ID', AC_I);
            CALL SYMPUTX('G_BURN_PRD', REDEEM_PERIOD);
            CALL SYMPUTX('G_BURN_PTS', REDEEMED_PTS);
        RUN;

        %PUT &G_ACCT_ID.;

        %FIRST_ACCT;

    %END;
    %ELSE %IF %EVAL(&G_REM_BURN_PTS. < 0)
    %THEN %DO;

        %REMAIN_BURN;
    %END;

This did not produce an error on the first pass but when it hits the 2nd, I get this error.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable ACCT_CT resolves to            2
MLOGIC(BURN_PTS):  %IF condition %EVAL(&ACCT_CT. = 1) is FALSE
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable G_REM_BURN_PTS resolves to 0)
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: %EVAL(&G_REM_BURN_PTS. < 0)
ERROR: The macro BURN_PTS will stop executing.
MLOGIC(BURN_PTS):  Ending execution.
Any help will be very much appreciated.
Since I have a %PUT &CT in the code and it does confirm it it as 2, my expectation is for the %IF to fail and the code drops to the %ELSE.

Instead of posting your real problem, please post a smaller example that illustrates the problem.  Meaning post an example dataset with 10 records.  And post two macros that where one calls the other, and they try to share information via macro variables.  It will be easier to help if you start with a small example that illustrates the macro language issues.  The macros should be as small as possible, to keep it simple.

A couple of issue you can investigate.
First you do not show any place where you have made a GLOBAL macro variable? Which macro variables should be global?  Is it one of the ones being set by CALL SYMPUTX()?  If so then add the optional third argument to force it to write into the GLONAL macro scope instead of the current local scope.
    CALL SYMPUTX('G_EARN_PRD', 201708, 'g');

Second if the dataset BURNED_HLD does not have any observations then the CALL SYMPUTX() functions will never execute.  So you need to decide what values should be set for the macro variables in that case.
